# How often should I water an Amaryllis plant?

Tags: watering, plant-health, plant-care, mold, amaryllis

I have a red amaryllis plant that is currently looking like it's doing well. It hasn't yet flowered and it is in a fairly early stage of growth. The plant care instructions said that it's important to water it enough to keep the soil always moist. However, white mold is starting to appear in the soil and around the base of the bulb. Should I water it less?

Here is a photo of the plant currently:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

How much to water is a complex question where you have to evaluate how much light is present, the relative humidity and the water needs of the plant.  Bulbs do not normally like wet feet.  The amaryllis is now in a period of fast growth using up the energy stored in the fall.

If the pot has drainage at the bottom and it is in high light then water thoroughly until water comes out the bottom of the pot.  Let the top half inch (1 cm) of soil dry out before watering again.

These plants benefit from being outside in the summer if they are allowed some time in the shade to get used to the much higher light levels present outside.

Answer (score 3):

It will have a period of very rapid growth and may need some support to prevent it toppling over. To keep this growth going it may need watering more frequently. Keep an eye on the compost if looking dry on top, water, but not kept waterlogged.